# Reading from stdin blocks at approx. 60 kB

Tags: c, stdin

When transforming files with a self-implemented burrows-wheeler algorithm my program gets stuck when reading files with filesize above 59 kB. 
Basically I'm starting my program in terminal:

```
./BW encode 4 < test
```

where 4 stands for 4*1024 bytes.
As told before when processing files (raw data, textfiles etc.) with filesize under 59 kB no problems occure.

code where data is processed and send to stdout:

```
void encodeBlock(unsigned char* str,long length){
    unsigned int i, out_rownum;
    unsigned char **str_matr, *out_str, *prnt_rt_str2, *prnt_rt_str1;
    str_matr = (unsigned char**) calloc(length,sizeof(unsigned char*));
    out_str = (unsigned char*) calloc(length+1,sizeof(unsigned char));
    // make matrix with rotationstrings of str (by saving pointer to first character)
    for(i=0;i<(unsigned int) length;i++){
        str_matr[i] = &str[i];
    }
    // sorting matrix
    glob_strt = &str[0];
    glob_length = length;
    qsort(str_matr,length,sizeof(unsigned char*),strCmpEnc);
    out_str[length] = '\0';
    for(i=0;i<(unsigned int) length;i++){
        prnt_rt_str1 = printRotStr(length,&str[0],str_matr[i]);
        prnt_rt_str2 = printRotStr(length,&prnt_rt_str1[0],&prnt_rt_str1[length-1]);
        if(memcmp(str,prnt_rt_str2,length) == 0){
            out_rownum = i;
        }
        out_str[i] = prnt_rt_str1[length-1];
    }    
    printf("(%d ",out_rownum);
    fwrite((unsigned char*) out_str, 1, length, stdout);
    printf(")\n");
    free(prnt_rt_str1);
    free(prnt_rt_str2);
    free(str_matr);
    free(out_str);
}
```

and code where data is received from stdin

```
void encode(unsigned short int num, unsigned int block_size){
    long b_length,length;
    unsigned char* buffer;  
    freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) calloc(block_size+1,sizeof(unsigned char));
    length = fread((unsigned char*) buffer, 1, block_size, stdin);
    if(length == 0){
        // file empty
    }else{
        b_length = length;
        printf("##B-W:%ld##\n",length);
        while(length == b_length){
            buffer[block_size] = '\0';
            encodeBlock(buffer,length);
            length = fread((unsigned char*) buffer, 1, block_size, stdin);      
        }
        if(length != 0){
            printf("##B-W:%ld##\n",length); 
            buffer[length] = '\0';
            encodeBlock(buffer,length);
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

When it gets stuck it usually terminates and 'Killed' appears on screen.
I'm working on linux OS.

Result using valgrind: 
The program gets stuck and my whole system hangs. I'm not able to see any debugging result because I have to shutdown my system manually.

UPDATE:
The reason behind the blocked reading (after 59kB) was that there was no space left on the heap due of many mem leaks. I solved this problem and finally reading works fine.

Comment: `if(memcmp(str,prnt_rt_str2,length) == 0){` goes beyond your allocated memory. It adresses (length-1)(length) characters. Update: That should have been (length+1)

Comment: Run the program under `valgrind` and fix the *very first* place where it tells you you accessed uninitialized or unallocated memory.  Repeat.

Comment: Well, 19 pairs of eyeballs are probably quicker.

Comment: @wildplasser;Zack Ok thanks but shouldn't I get a segment fault error than?

Comment: If I understanding correctly, you are setting up two stringpointer arrays, with each pointer pointing to an individual character of the input string. With the only goal to permute/shuffle the input string ?

Comment: Nothing is faster than running it through gdb…

Comment: No basically i'm using an array with char pointers. The idea is that these pointers can be accessed and used to get the following characters from str. For example let there be a string "test". At the first index i'm saving a pointer which points to 't', at the second i'm saving a pointer which points to 'e' etc... When I want to construct a permutationstring of "test" beginning with 'e', I simply start with the pointer to 'e', save this, go to pointer which points to 's' and this until I reach the last pointer (to 't'). In that case I restart with the pointer to the first character...

Comment: And when the program would access uninitialized or unallocated memory I normally should have this problem also for files under 59 kB which is not the case...

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying. You are using pokes to shuffle insects. WRT 59K limit. Malloc/sbrk /mmap work in mysterious ways. The probably preallocate a chunk of pages (say 64K), which are already in your process's address space but still on the free list. The segfault occurs once your program crosses the boundary. BTW: you still have not ansered why you are memcmp()ing lenght bytes.

Comment: I use this for the decimal number for my BW tuple... The line above constructs the next permutationstring of the current permutationstring . For example: on iteration i of the for loop we have "estt" as the current permutationstring. The line above memcmp constructs the next perm.str => "test". Memcmp() detects that this string matches "test" so we use i as decimal number for our tuple.

Comment: Anyways I tried using valgrind without any results... The program gets stuck and my whole system hangs. I'm not able to see any debugging result because I have to shutdown my system manually.

Answer (score 0):

> When it gets stuck it usually terminates and 'Killed' appears on screen.

This means, most likely, it runs out of the memory limit and is killed by the kernel.

Do use valgrind, honestly. Your code is too painful to read for humans to be able to point at the fatal error (non-fatal, but still annoying ones abound).

Comment: Anyways I tried using valgrind without any results... The program gets stuck and my whole system hangs. I'm not able to see any debugging result because I have to shut down my system manually.

Comment: @user1745184 Are you saying that you have to shut down the _computer_ while running your application under valgrind? As far as I know, Ctrl+C should interrupt the valgrind process just as it would any other.

Comment: Even if I run my program in the terminal my computer freezes.

Comment: @user1745184 Run it in Valgrind with a small parameter (like 4) so that you can find the memory leak (or other problems.)